# Git fetch not fetching from upstream

Tags: git, github, git-remote, github-cli

I have cloned a fork repo using [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) `gh`:

```
gh repo clone felipeplets/Auto-GPT
```

In order to check out an upstream branch locally I then ran:

```
git fetch --all
git switch -c stable upstream/stable
```

I received the message error message, although I checked and the stable branch exists in the remote upstream:

```
fatal: invalid reference: upstream/stable
```

I then listed all branches by using:

```
git branch -r
```

And have the following result:

```
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  upstream/master
```

I have always done this to checkout upstream branches but somewhat it is not working for this repository and I can't seem to find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of tests, I opened the `.git/config` file and saw that the upstream configuration portion was like below:

```
[remote "upstream"]
    url = git@github.com:Significant-Gravitas/Auto-GPT.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/upstream/master
```

Once I changed master by `*` in the fetch line above the result was like this:

```
[remote "upstream"]
    url = git@github.com:Significant-Gravitas/Auto-GPT.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

I was then able to successfully create a local branch based on an upstream branch with the original command I used:

```
git fetch --all
git switch -c stable upstream/stable
```